Beginner's question: proper way to handle hyphenation of words of short length?
For the sample, below, without adjusting for hyphenation, the word "yielded" in the first line extends into the right margin. I thought the correct hyphenation would be "yield-ed" but learned that it is ignored because, in English, the \righthyphenmin has a default of 3.
Which is correct in such a case: make it "yiel-ded" or set \righthyphenmin to 2?
If the latter, can or should it be done for the entire document or just for the word(s)?
Thank you.
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,openright,twoside,titlepage]{book}
\usepackage[
 letterpaper,
 includeall,
 twoside,
 inner = 1.5in,
 textwidth = 5in,
 textheight = 9in
]{geometry}
\renewcommand\rmdefault{LibertinusSerif-LF}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[expansion=false]{microtype}

\newdimen\origiwspc%
\origiwspc=\fontdimen2\font% original inter word space
\righthyphenmin 2
\hyphenation{yield-ed}
%\hyphenation{yiel-ded}

\begin{document}
\fontdimen2\font=1.1\origiwspc
1.\ \textsc{The} earth, the past year, under the smiles of Providence, has yielded to industrious husbandmen, a plentiful increase. A partial drought has indeed, in some instances, disappointed their expectations.
\end{document}





Did you try package babel?

Load babel as @MS-SPO says with the correct variant of English for your text. Even when words are spelt the same, hyphenation patterns differ significantly. If you are not writing US English, the default patterns will be wrong. If you are writing US English, the default patterns will be of poorer quality and less complete. You should not need to specify manual hyphenation for common words. If TeX can't find a good place to break a line without altering the default for yielded, something is wrong or your document is of a specialist type.

@cfr the code selects libertinus in a full texlive distribution

For English language texts, a serious drawback of switching from \righthyphenmin=3 to \righthyphenmin=2 is that the existing hyphenation patterns have been created under the assumption that  \righthyphenmin=3 is in effect. If you make the switch to \righthyphenmin=2, you may get lucky in some cases, i.e., get additional and correct hyphenation points for words such as "yielded", "welded", and "rounded". However, you may also run into cases such as "hor-se" and "alo-ne", for which the newly discovered hyphenation points may simply be inappropriate.

Thank you. I had babel and microtype loaded in the actual document file but forgot to add them here (edited now). I have microtype with no expansion because, when printed, there were locations at which the font appeared obviously thicker. With expansion, the line is shrunk such that "yiedled" fits on the first line.

Note that your fontdimen setting is basing the modified libertinus setting on 1.1 times the setting from computer modern, but that's not directly related to your question.
I would not change \righthyphenmin as that potentially affects the whole document, just to correct one problematic paragraph.
If you can not re-word, possible options are to add a hyphenation point for this specific case with \- or to allow more stretch white space:

\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,openright,twoside,titlepage]{book}
\usepackage[
 letterpaper,
 includeall,
 twoside,
 inner = 1.5in,
 textwidth = 5in,
 textheight = 9in
]{geometry}
\renewcommand\rmdefault{LibertinusSerif-LF}
\newdimen\origiwspc%
\origiwspc=\fontdimen2\font% original inter word space
%\righthyphenmin 2
\hyphenation{yield-ed}
%\hyphenation{yiel-ded}

\begin{document}
\fontdimen2\font=1.1\origiwspc
1.\ \textsc{The} earth, the past year, under the smiles of Providence, has yield\-ed to industrious husbandmen, a plentiful increase. A partial drought has indeed, in some instances, disappointed their expectations.

\begin{sloppypar}
2.\ \textsc{The} earth, the past year, under the smiles of Providence, has yielded to industrious husbandmen, a plentiful increase. A partial drought has indeed, in some instances, disappointed their expectations.
\end{sloppypar}
\end{document}


Thank you for the answer and for pointing out the issue with the word-spacinig.

You can also load the microtype package, or if you are too picky with the liberal sloppypar, you can set directly \hyphenpenalty, \tolerance and \emergencystretch just to the minimal values to solve the issues, although in this example I think this will not make any difference in any case.
  \documentclass[draft,letterpaper,12pt,openright,twoside,titlepage]{book}
    \usepackage[
     includeall,
     inner = 1.5in,
     textwidth = 5in,
     textheight = 9in
    ]{geometry}
    \renewcommand\rmdefault{LibertinusSerif-LF}
    \newdimen\origiwspc%
    \origiwspc=\fontdimen2\font% original inter word space
    \usepackage{microtype} 
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    

\begin{document}
\fontdimen2\font=1.1\origiwspc
\parskip1em

\noindent\verb!microtype (default settings)!:

1.\ \textsc{The} earth, the past year, under the smiles of Providence, has yielded to industrious husbandmen, a plentiful increase. A partial drought has indeed, in some instances, disappointed their expectations.

\microtypesetup{activate=false} 

\noindent\verb!raw text!:

1.\ \textsc{The} earth, the past year, under the smiles of Providence, has yielded to industrious husbandmen, a plentiful increase. A partial drought has indeed, in some instances, disappointed their expectations. 

\noindent\verb!\emergencystretch!:

{% group to use the solution only in this paragraph
\hyphenpenalty=0
\tolerance=1000
\emergencystretch=.8em 
1.\ \textsc{The} earth, the past year, under the smiles of Providence, has yielded to industrious husbandmen, a plentiful increase. A partial drought has indeed, in some instances, disappointed their expectations.
\par} % Do not forget end of paragrah in the gruop!!

\end{document}


Nice answer (+1), however you should remove letterpaper and twoside from document class options or from geometry package options. Their appearance in both options cause error.

ah I came back here to see if adding microtype changed my answer and see you've already posted, saves me adding it to mine +1 :-)

Thank you. Even though, in this particular instance, the results of sloppypar and emergencystretch may be the same, this will be good to know when more complex issues arise.

@Zarko Of course it have not sense the duplicated option ( just copied the MWE of the question without pay attention to this), but for me it work as it was. Edited anyway.
